# Delaying Evaluation with Abstractions in the Y-Combinator

Tags: python, lambda, evaluation, delayed-execution, fixpoint-combinators

I am having some problem wrapping my head around how evaluation delaying works. I am trying to understand it with the Y-Combinator:

If we write a simple version of the Y-Combinator we get problems with infinite recursion:

```
Ysimple = (lambda f : (lambda x : f(x(x))) (lambda x : f(x(x))))
```

When we build a recursive function, the problem appears:

```
almost_factorial = lambda f : lambda n : 1 if n == 0 else n * f(n-1)

factorial = Ysimp(almost_factorial) # <- infinite recursion
```

> Ysimple = (lambda f : (lambda x : f(x(x))) (lambda x : f(x(x)) ))
>   [Previous line repeated 995 more times] RecursionError: maximum
>   recursion depth exceeded

But we can wrap either the second or both of the `f(x(x))`-expressions in a delaying abstraction:

```
Ydelay = (lambda f : (lambda x : f(x(x))) (lambda x : f(lambda y: x(x)(y))) )
```

And now the code works just fine. But why?

If we have ONLY `Ysimple` in our file nothing gets evaluated. So I assume only lambdas get evaluated that are the top-level expression.

I did some manual evaluation steps but I don't see the reason in them for the delay happening:

```
Ysimple F =  (lambda f : (lambda x : f(x(x))) (lambda x : f(lambda y: x(x)(y)))) F
          -> (lambda x : F(x(x))) (lambda x : F(lambda y: x(x)(y)))
          -> F( (lambda x : F(lambda y: x(x)(y))) (lambda x : F(lambda y: x(x)(y))) )


Ydelay F =  (lambda f : (lambda x : f(x(x))) (lambda x : f(x(x)))) F
         -> (lambda x : F(x(x))) (lambda x : F(x(x)))
         -> F( (lambda x : F(x(x))) (lambda x : F(x(x))) )
```

Where does the delay happen here? In both cases `F` is the top-level expression and also in both cases `lambda x` is at level below `F`. What role does the delay `lambda y` play?

## Edit:

Similarly, why how does the delay work in the first line here:

```
(lambda x : x(x)) (lambda y: lambda x : x(x)(y))
(lambda x : x(x)) (lambda x: x(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

When we translate the lambda expressions into ordinary function syntax the whole thing becomes more apparent:

```
def f(x):                       # lambda x : x(x)
    return x(x)

def g(y):                       # lambda y: lambda x : x(x)(y)
    def fg(x):
        return (x(x))(y)
    return fg


f(g) # does not recurse infinitely
```

When we manually evaluate the expression corresponding to `(lambda x : x(x)) (lambda y: (lambda x : x(x))(y))` we get

```
f(g) = g(g) = lambda x : x(x)(g)
```

while evaluating the one corresponding to `(lambda x : x(x)) (lambda y: y(y))` yields

```
f(f) = f(f) = f(f) = ...
```

And we can now see why the abstraction halts the recursion.